# "Error while downloading <application_name>. There is insufficient space on the device"

Tags: insufficient-memory

When I am downloading the application from the Play Store, I am getting this message.

```
"Error while downloading <application_name>. There is insufficient space on the device"
```

I am using Sony Xperia C and I have sufficient space in the internal memory and in the memory card. This message is cracking my brain as it is shown for the application under 2 mb and I have almost half GB free.
I am not able to update the applications too.

Please help me to solve this issue. I am using android 4.2.2.

Comment: I've just added the 'insufficient-memory' tag to your question. Please see its [tag-wiki](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/insufficient-memory/info) to get started. It's important to see where the storage-hog lies: the error only applies to "device storage", and has nothing to do with (internal or external) SD cards.

Comment: Sometimes a simple restart would help. Can you add a screenshot of the storage chart?

Comment: @Eugine Did you tried moving apps to sdcarD?

Comment: Yes, I do. still it is same error.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Clear cache of the apps which you don't use often, that will solve this issue. Also uninstall the apps which you no longer need.

`Go to Settings --> Apps --> <App_name> ( scroll down ) --> Clear cache.`

Answer (score 2):

If you have tried other methods with no success, you can try rebooting your device into Android System Recovery mode and using the "wipe cache partition" option.

Instructions for a Samsung device are below.  Other manufacturers devices will be similar but some have different keys to get into recovery mode.

1. Turn off your phone (Make sure it is completely off. If possible take out the battery then place it back in)
2. With the handset turned off, press and hold the Volume Up key.
3. While holding down the Volume Up key, press and hold the Home key.
4. With both the Volume Up key and the Home key held down, press and hold the Power key.
5. Release all three keys when the Samsung logo appears.
6. Press the Volume Down key to scroll to ***wipe cache partition***.
7. With ***wipe cache partition*** highlighted, press the Power key.
8. Once the Cache wipe is complete, press the Power key to select
   reboot system now.

The Cache wipe is now complete. The handset will restart.